# position text bar chart stacked ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-plotly

I want to write correctly percentage in each part ?How to write the percentages well in each part? and if there is easier with plot_ly i'm okay.

Code :

```
mois = c("avril",   "avril",   "avril",   "avril",   "mai",     "mai",     "mai",     "mai", "juin", "juin",  "juin",   "juin",    "juillet", "juillet", "juillet", "juillet", "aout", "aout",    "aout",    "aout",    "sept",    "sept",    "sept",    "sept")

pourcentage = c(56.7, 10.0, 13.3, 20.0, 64.5,  0.0,  3.2, 32.3, 73.3,  6.7,  3.3, 16.7, 54.8, 12.9,  9.7, 22.6, 45.2, 12.9,  6.5, 35.5, 10.0 , 0.0,  3.3, 86.7)

class = c("=< -5%",    "-5 et 0 %", "0 - 5%",    ">= 5%",     "=< -5%",    "-5 et 0 %", "0 - 5%",    ">= 5%",     "=< -5%",    "-5 et 0 %", "0 - 5%",    ">= 5%",     "=< -5%",    "-5 et 0 %", "0 - 5%",    ">= 5%",     "=< -5%",    "-5 et 0 %", "0 - 5%",    ">= 5%",     "=< -5%",    "-5 et 0 %", "0 - 5%",    ">= 5%" )

table = as.data.frame(cbind(mois, pourcentage, class))
```

[image]

```
color <- c("green", "blue", "red", "yellow")
    


bar =  table %>%
 ggplot(mapping = aes(x = mois, 
                 y = pourcentage))+
 geom_bar(aes(fill = class), 
     position = 'fill',  # Use position = fill to use proportions.
     stat = 'identity',
     color = "black")+
scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+
 geom_text(aes(label = paste0(pourcentage,"%")),
 position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5,
                   reverse = TRUE),
                    size = 2)+
theme_classic()+
scale_fill_manual(values = color)

ggplotly(bar)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. Your text positioning had the `reverse = TRUE` parameter. You'd need the same on the bars for them to align.
2. Your bars had fill mapped to `class`, which tells ggplot to do the stacking of bars based on that variable and the way it is sorted. The text did not have fill or color specified, so the stacking would happen in order of appearance in the data. To make it stack the same way, you can specify `group = class` either globally (as I have done) or in `aes()` for the `geom_text` layer.

Revised:

```
table %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = mois, 
                       y = pourcentage, group = class))+
  geom_bar(aes(fill = class), 
           position = position_fill(reverse = TRUE),  # Use position = fill to use proportions.
           stat = 'identity',
           color = "black")+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(pourcentage,"%")),
            position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5,
                                     reverse = TRUE),
            size = 2)+
  theme_classic()+
  scale_fill_manual(values = color)
```

[image]